# Key fob stopped working

Tags: mercedes-benz, key, fob

I have a 2010 Mercedes GLK 350, and my key fob has stopped working. I cannot lock or unlock doors nor start car. Today at several different stops the car would not lock right away after stopping -- this happened several times today and then finally stopped working completely.  I had the same problem a few months ago and I simply retrieved my second key and it worked fine with that key. Now that key failed today. What can it be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Comment: did you check the battery of the fob? you have not described if its a push start or a standard key